# How to get systemd running correctly?

Tags: systemd, openvpn

I'm currently trying to set up a OpenVPN on a Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy) server, via SSH. I haven't really used Linux before, so I'm completely new to the terminal etc. 
However, in a guide that I followed, it said to run `systemctl restart openvpn@server`.
I got an error saying that `systemctl` wasn't found or so.. so I installed systemd. But now I get a different error: `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /run/systemd/private: No such file or directory`

Any idea what that means? Is this issue even related to systemd? Or is it an OpenVPN issue?

Comment: Is `dbus` installed? If not, `apt-get install dbus` and then restart

Comment: Interesting, now it only says: `Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.` Any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: Is dbus running? `/etc/init.d/dbus start`

Comment: Yes, it was already running.

Comment: Could you please execute `systemctl is-system-running` ?

Comment: I got `Unknown operation is-system-running`. Is it possible that this isn't working because it's not configured to start with the OS? Some people on the internet are suggesting to make edits to /boot/grub/menu.lst or /etc/lilo.conf ... but /lilo.conf and /grub/ do not exist on my system...

Comment: Yes, from what I can see you have installed systemd but not using it. Could you please execute `ls -l /etc/init.d/ | grep -i vpn` ?

Comment: It retured: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8958 Feb 24   20012 openvpn`

Comment: Try `/etc/init.d/openvpn start`

Comment: returned this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=h6g2kUR1

Comment: Did you run it as root? Have you configured properly your opevnpn configuration?

Comment: I can't say for sure if I have it configured properly.

Comment: Did you run it as root?

Comment: Yes, I don't even know if there is a non-root account on that server.

Answer (score 4):

Systemd is an "init system" for Linux -- this is the first process started by the kernel when the system boots, and it is responsible for starting everything else.  Your system already had an init process on it, so installing and using systemd isn't necessary to do what you want.

The error you're seeing suggests that systemd isn't actually running, which means that it has either not been configured correctly or it may simply mean you need to reboot first.

I would suggest either:

- Using a distribution that uses systemd "out of the box", like Fedora, CentOS, Arch Linux, etc, or
- Find a guide for Debian that is not written around systemd.

Either of these options will substantially simplify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I rebooted and still got the same error message. Is there maybe an alternative command for `systemd restart` in debian 7? Unfortunately I can't install a different distro on that server. :/ I also couldn't find another helpful guide for my distro...

Comment: @Forivin There is an "alternative" command: `service ... restart`. It's not really an alternative; it controls an alternative init system (which you seem to have installed). But it is *NOT* a drop-in replacement. You can't just write `service openvpn@server restart`. I suggest you read some documentation on Debian 7 and controlling services; explaining init systems is not fit for Q&A format. (Note: this comment is not directed to @larsks.)